# Find $m$ so that $r(A^{-1})=2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &3  &1  &1 \\ 
2 &2  &-1  &0 \\ 
2 &4  &-2  &0 \\ 
0 &-1  &2  &m 
\end{pmatrix}$

### Find $m$ so that $r(A^{-1})=2$.

I have posted a similar problem before and they told me try to find $m$ such that $A$ is invertible. But i still feel it isn't enough. With the condition of $m$ such that $A$ is invertible ( $m\neq \frac{5}{3}$ ), how could we know that $r(A^{-1})=2$.

Comment: In order for $A^{-1}$ to exist, $A$ must have full rank ($=4$), so that is impossible.

Comment: If the inverse exists, then it would have full rank (4), so how could it be 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for the rank of $A^{-1}$ to be $2$. As you know for the existence of $A^{-1}$ we must have $A$ is non singular, in that case $r(A)=4$. Also we know if $A$ is invertible then so is $A^{-1}$, i.e., $A^{-1}$ will also become non-singular. Hence it's rank will also must be $4$.